# Video player: Play,Pause, forward and backward methods IOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, video-player

[image]

How to get this buttons event/delegate(Play,Pause, forward and backward) with time difference.

Here i have put the code below. Please suggest we can use other player for this events

```
player = AVPlayer(url:URL(fileURLWithPath: objpdfURL));
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VedioPlayVC.didfinishplaying(note:)),name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(VedioPlayVC.Stop(note:)), name: .kAVPlayerViewControllerDismissingNotification, object: nil);

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VedioPlayVC.Jump(note:)),name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemTimeJumped, object: nil)

playerController.player = player
playerController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
playerController.delegate = self
playerController.player?.play()
self.present(playerController,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
@IBAction func btnPlayAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if isVideoPlaying{
        player.pause()
        sender.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
    }else{
        player.play()
        sender.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
    }
    isVideoPlaying = !isVideoPlaying
}

@IBAction func btnForwardAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let duration = player.currentItem?.duration else { return }
    let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    let newTime = currentTime + 5.0
    if newTime < (CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) - 5.0){
        let time: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime*1000), timescale: 1000)
        player.seek(to: time)
    }
}
@IBAction func btnBackwardAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    var newTime = currentTime - 5.0

    if newTime < 0{
        newTime = 0
    }
    let time: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime*1000), timescale: 1000)
    player.seek(to: time)

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate this method using view ?